# Why doesn't Internet Explorer accept Access-Control-Allow-Headers longer than 1023 characters (CORS request)

Tags: internet-explorer, asp.net-web-api, xmlhttprequest, cross-domain, odata

After a bit of cross-domain testing our web-api, it seems that IE fails to process the response value of the Access-Control-Allow-Headers when its value is longer than 1023 characters (which is processed during the pre-flight OPTIONS request). Chrome however succeeds at processing the request.

This is the javascript which I use to send the request to the service (web-api OData service):

```html
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
xhr.open("PATCH", "http://www.example.com/Services.Web/odata/runtime/Products", true)
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
xhr.send(JSON.stringify({"ID": 5, "Active": true}))
```

When I send this request using IE 10 or Edge **and** the server responds to the pre-flight request with an Access-Control-Allow-Headers where its value is **longer than 1023 characters**, I will get the following error:

> SEC7123: Request header content-type was not present in the
>   Access-Control-Allow-Headers list

When I send the same request using Chrome, everything works as expected.

When I update the web server to contain 1023 or less characters in the Access-Control-Allow-Headers, IE 10 and Edge also succeed at processing the request.

Keep in mind that this only occurs when cross-domain requests are made (so when you test it, make sure your request header **Origin** is from another domain than the one hosting the service). Testing on the same origin always succeeds because there will be no pre-flight request and the Access-Control-Allow-Headers are never processed by the browser.

To complete the example this is an Access-Control-Allow-Headers that works on chrome but **not** on IE:

```
<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type, Accept, Accept-CH, Accept-Charset, Accept-Datetime, Accept-Encoding, Accept-Ext, Accept-Features, Accept-Language, Accept-Params, Accept-Ranges, Access-Control-Allow-Credentials, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Access-Control-Allow-Methods, Access-Control-Allow-Origin, Access-Control-Expose-Headers, Access-Control-Max-Age, Access-Control-Request-Headers, Access-Control-Request-Method, Age, Allow, Alternates, Authentication-Info, Authorization, C-Ext, C-Man, C-Opt, C-PEP, C-PEP-Info, CONNECT, Cache-Control, Compliance, Connection, Content-Base, Content-Disposition, Content-Encoding, Content-ID, Content-Language, Content-Length, Content-Location, Content-MD5, Content-Range, Content-Script-Type, Content-Security-Policy, Content-Style-Type, Content-Transfer-Encoding, Content-Version, Cookie, Cost, DAV, DELETE, DNT, DPR, Date, Default-Style, Delta-Base, Depth, Derived-From, Destination, Differential-ID, Digest, ETag, Expect, Expires, Ext, From, GET, GetProfile, HEAD, HTTP-date, Host, IM, If, If-Match, If-Modified-Since, If-None-Match, If-Range, If-Unmodified-Since, Keep-Alive, Label, Last-Event-ID, Last-Modified, Link, Location, Lock-Token, MIME-Version, Man, Max-Forwards, Media-Range, Message-ID, Meter, Negotiate, Non-Compliance, OPTION, OPTIONS, OWS, Opt, Optional, Ordering-Type, Origin, Overwrite, P3P, PEP, PICS-Label, POST, PUT, Pep-Info, Permanent, Position, Pragma, ProfileObject, Protocol, Protocol-Query, Protocol-Request, Proxy-Authenticate, Proxy-Authentication-Info, Proxy-Authorization, Proxy-Features, Proxy-Instruction, Public, RWS, Range, Referer, Refresh, Resolution-Hint, Resolver-Location, Retry-After, Safe, Sec-Websocket-Extensions, Sec-Websocket-Key, Sec-Websocket-Origin, Sec-Websocket-Protocol, Sec-Websocket-Version, Security-Scheme, Server, Set-Cookie, Set-Cookie2, SetProfile, SoapAction, Status, Status-URI, Strict-Transport-Security, SubOK, Subst, Surrogate-Capability, Surrogate-Control, TCN, TE, TRACE, Timeout, Title, Trailer, Transfer-Encoding, UA-Color, UA-Media, UA-Pixels, UA-Resolution, UA-Windowpixels, URI, Upgrade, User-Agent, Variant-Vary, Vary, Version, Via, Viewport-Width, WWW-Authenticate, Want-Digest, Warning, Width, X-Content-Duration, X-Content-Security-Policy, X-Content-Type-Options, X-CustomHeader, X-DNSPrefetch-Control, X-Forwarded-For, X-Forwarded-Port, X-Forwarded-Proto, X-Frame-Options, X-Modified, X-OTHER, X-PING, X-PINGOTHER, X-Powered-By, X-Requested-With" />
```

*I know these are a lot of headers, but in our test case, this is required.*

This is an Access-Control-Allow-Headers where all browsers succeed at processing the request:

```
<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type, Accept, Accept-CH, Accept-Charset, Accept-Datetime, Accept-Encoding, Accept-Ext, Accept-Features, Accept-Language, Accept-Params, Accept-Ranges, Access-Control-Allow-Credentials, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Access-Control-Allow-Methods, Access-Control-Allow-Origin, Access-Control-Expose-Headers, Access-Control-Max-Age, Access-Control-Request-Headers, Access-Control-Request-Method, Age, Allow, Alternates, Authentication-Info, Authorization, C-Ext, C-Man, C-Opt, C-PEP, C-PEP-Info, CONNECT, Cache-Control, Compliance, Connection, Content-Base, Content-Disposition, Content-Encoding, Content-ID, Content-Language, Content-Length, Content-Location, Content-MD5, Content-Range, Content-Script-Type, Content-Security-Policy, Content-Style-Type, Content-Transfer-Encoding, Content-Version, Cookie, Cost, DAV, DELETE, DNT, DPR, Date, Default-Style, Delta-Base, Depth, Derived-From, Destination, Differential-ID, Digest, ETag, Expect, Expires, Ext, From, GET, GetProfile, HEAD, HTTP-date, Host, IM, If, If-Match" />
```

The actual error returned from IE complains about the content-type header, but as you can see, that header is placed first in both examples. If I change it to lowercase, it doesn't solve anything. Also wildcarding the Access-Control-Allow-Headers with an asterisk '*' is not a solution because this is not supported by the browsers.

The real question: is this a known limitation of IE or am I overseeing something?

Comment: Its a bug most certainly. I'm seeing this now as well.

Comment: Did you find the solution in the end?

Comment: No. Unfortunately not. I suspect this may be fixed in a future version of IE but for now we're using Chrome and outside our testing environment, not that many headers are processed.